# Where can I find dried Great Northern Beans?

Tags: beans

In a recipe I am trying to make this weekend, I saw the following:

"2 cups dried Great Northern Beans, soaked,
cooked and drained"

Where can I find these?  I could not find them at my local grocery store.  Are there any substitutions that would work well?

Comment: Not sure where your located but I find mine at Wegman's and the canned version I've seen many times at Safeway and Harris Teeter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are a small, white, mildly flavored bean. You can use cannellini or navy beans instead.

Comment: Cannellini beans are also known as white kidney beans.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I did see kidney beans at the store.  I'll pick some up.

Comment: Just to be clear: NOT the red kidney beans. Depending on what you are doing with them, it could be fine, but will be quite a bit different than Great Northern. But as @hobodave says, white kidney is indeed the same as GNB.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Like the other respondants said, other white beans of a similar size/shape would make fine substitutions. The GNBs have a very mild flavor. I would even say other off-color beans would be fine, like canellini or kidney beans if your don't mind the color mix.

Answer (score 1):

I thought Great Northern beans and Navy beans were the same. Look in ethnic markets, they have a great range of dry beans and different types of rices, also a good place to look for large quantities of spices if you make your own spice mixtures.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally a lot of farmers markets will carry dried beans/lentils/rice. The one I frequent has a large variety for a low cost. Worth a shot.